# Binomial or Uniform Probability?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of rolling exactly two sixes in $7$ rolls of a die?

I know this is a binomial probability.

$P(X=2)=\binom{7}{2}(1/6)^2(5/6)^5$.

By the definition of probability formula *"Probability formula is the ratio of number of favorable outcomes to the total number of possible outcomes."* Then why probability of rolling exactly two sixes in $7$ rolls of a die isn't $=2/42$? The denominator is $42$ because in one die there are $6$ faces, and in $7$ rolls of a die, there are $7\times 6=42$ faces.

Comment: Because you have two dices I think and so "two ways" of having two sixes, even though it doesn't seem to make much sense

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. The "probability of rolling exactly two sixes in 6 rolls of a die" should be ${6\choose 2}{1 \over 6^2}{5 \over 6^4} \neq {2\over 42}$ no?

Comment: I imagine you are asking **why** the probability of rolling exactly two sixes in **7** rolls of a die **isn't** $2 \over 42$?

Comment: @gowrath yes, you're right. I am editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The total number of possible outcomes is $6^7$. In each try we have $6$ possibilities, and we repeat it for $7$ times. So $6^7$ in denomerator.

The number of favorable outcomes is $\binom{7}{2}5^5$. To see why, consider one of the cases such as `66?????`, where each `?` can have $5$ possibilities. So for this specific selection  of the order of the two six, we have $5^5$ possibilities. There are $\binom{7}{2}$ possibilities for selecting the positions of the two $6$.

The probability is therefore $$\frac{\binom{7}{2}5^5}{6^7}$$

Comment: Suppose I have 7 balls, among which 3 are red and 4 green. What is the probability that if I randomly draw 4  balls two of them are red? can I use here the formula $\text{Probability}=\frac{\text{number of favorable outcomes}}{\text{total number of possible outcomes}}$? I suspect because total number of possible outcome is not $2^4$, since if first 3 balls are red, the fourth ball must be green.

Comment: @user81411 The number of favorable outcomes is $\binom{4}{2}\binom{3}{2}$ and the total number of outcomes is $\binom{7}{4}$.

Comment: hm..., it becomes hypergeometric. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Define $X_{1},X_{2},\ldots,X_{7}$ as Bernoulli random variables, such that $X_{i}=1$ when the $i$th die lands $6$ and $X_{i}=0$ otherwise. Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^{6}{X_{i}}$ be the number of sixes in $7$ die rolls.

**Probability of $X$ sixes in $7$ rolls of a die**.

The number of sixes $X$ follows binomial distribution. $X\sim{Binomial(7,1/6)}$.

$\displaystyle{P(X=2)={{7}\choose{2}}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5}$

**Probability of a certain outcome, given that you land $2$ sixes in $7$ rolls of a die**.

The naive definition of probability which states that,

$$P(A)=\frac{\text{number of sample points in }A}{\text{total number of points in sample space }S}$$

is applicable, when the sample space $S$ is finite and the sample points are equally likely.

Given that we land $2$ sixes in $7$ die rolls, i.e. the event $\{X=2\}$, what is the likelihood of any particular outcome, say,

$\{X_{1}=0,X_{2}=1,X_{3}=0,X_{4}=1,X_{5}=0,X_{6}=0,X_{7}=0\}$

Each such outcome occurs with equal probability. The sample space $S$ consists of ${{7}\choose{2}}=21$ such sequences. Therefore,

$\displaystyle{P(X_{1}=0,X_{2}=1,X_{3}=0,X_{4}=1,X_{5}=0,X_{6}=0,X_{7}=0|X=2)=\frac{1}{21}}$

Given $X=2$, these are uniformly distributed.

*Note. In the strict sense of term, I have computed conditional probability above. It is $P(A|B)=P(AB)/P(B)$, where $P(AB)=(1/6)^2(5/6)^5$ and $P(B)={{7}\choose{2}}(1/6)^2(5/6)^5$.*